# Notation in Paper on Haag-Lopuszanski-Sohnius Theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators, symmetry

In section 2 of 'All possible generators of supersymmetries of the S-matrix', an operator $G$ on the Hilbert space of states is introduced that has to commute with the S-matrix and act additively on multiple particle states. They state that this requirements are equivalent to $G$ inducing  an infinitesimal transformation on the space of fields

$\Psi \rightarrow \Psi + \epsilon \delta_G \Psi$

such that $\delta_G(\Psi(x)) =  i [G,\Psi(x)]_{\pm}$ (sign depending on the type of operator and field) is again local. I am a mathematician, so I am not really familiar with this notation. Can someone explain what this $\delta_G$ is? Is is some kind of derivation, or even an operator that acts on the space of fields? As far as I know, such an infinitesimal transformation would be given by a family of sections of the pullback bundles

$\xi_{\Psi} \in \Gamma(M;\Psi^* TX)$,

but I do not see how this would come to play here.

Comment: Are you familiar with the same notation utilized in the [calculus of variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations#Variations_and_sufficient_condition_for_a_minimum) of ordinary functions?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I do not think so. I read about classical field theory, and they used something called variational one form, but I have not seen a similar notation.

Comment: The overwhelming majority of physics texts use this notation, loosely defined in the WP link.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Do you know any further literature that explains the notion in QFT?

Comment: Not really, many good texts define their terms... Classical mechanics books spend more time on the notation, as QFT is not too different... it only involves functions of operators... [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) might help...